# Automatic display the data into listview when new data inserted into mysqldatabase without refreshing the class in android

Tags: android, listview

I want to display the inserted data into listview automatically without refreshing the class in android.. Here is my code to display data in listview but the problem is when there is new inserted data it will not display unless if i refresh the class. The Data display in listview is from mySql Database.

```
  /**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayAll.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading routes. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String num = c.getString(TAG_NO);
                    String  route= c.getString(TAG_ROUTE);
                    String cloc = c.getString(TAG_CLOC);
                  //  String dloc = c.getString(TAG_DLOC);
                    String btype = c.getString(TAG_BUSTYPE);
                    String aseats = c.getString(TAG_ASEATS);
                    String lastup = c.getString(TAG_LASTUP);
                    String estime = c.getString(TAG_ESTIME);
                    String dot = c.getString(TAG_DOT);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NO, num);
                    map.put(TAG_ROUTE, route);
                    map.put(TAG_CLOC, cloc);
                   // map.put(TAG_DLOC, dloc);
                    map.put(TAG_BUSTYPE, btype);
                    map.put(TAG_ASEATS, aseats);
                    map.put(TAG_LASTUP, lastup);
                    map.put(TAG_ESTIME, estime);
                    map.put(TAG_DOT, dot);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                  //      NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                //startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
               ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        DisplayAll.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_info, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NO,TAG_ROUTE,TAG_CLOC,TAG_BUSTYPE,TAG_ASEATS,TAG_LASTUP,TAG_ESTIME,TAG_DOT},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.bno,R.id.broute,R.id.bcloc,R.id.btype,R.id.bas,R.id.lastup,R.id.bet,R.id.dot });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use this `notifyDataSetChanged()`, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: You don't need `runOnUiThread()` in `onPostExecute()`. This method always runs on the UI thread.

Comment: @Jiyeh Can u elaborate?

Comment: @Chong check my answer. Hope it helps:)

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430885/how-to-update-listview-when-back-pressed-from-another-activity-android/35431272#35431272

Answer (score 0):

For your case:

**Edited**
Define your Adapter outside of your AsynClass, probably in your activity class like this:

```
private BaseAdapter adapter; // Global Define
```

And in your onCreate() method:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        DisplayAll.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_info, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NO,TAG_ROUTE,TAG_CLOC,TAG_BUSTYPE,TAG_ASEATS,TAG_LASTUP,TAG_ESTIME,TAG_DOT},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.bno,R.id.broute,R.id.bcloc,R.id.btype,R.id.bas,R.id.lastup,R.id.bet,R.id.dot });
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then inside your onPostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // you don't need to runOnUiThread as onPostExecute itself is running on UiThread
        // your productsList by now should contain updated data
        Log.d("All Products List: ", productsList.toString());

        // updating listview
        //setListAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // This will do the trick!

    }
```

Comment: its doesn`t work.. my class will not load it will automatic exit

Comment: What do you mean by automatic exit?

Comment: What does the Log say?

Comment: @Jiyeh . The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter so that i make it ..  ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged(); and it will automatic exit

Comment: @Jiyeh .... 02-17 12:48:39.287: E/AndroidRuntime(32658):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
02-17 12:48:39.287: E/AndroidRuntime(32658):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
02-17 12:48:39.287: E/AndroidRuntime(32658):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
02-17 12:48:39.287: E/AndroidRuntime(32658):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you insert new record into database , get all the new records from database at the same time and store into arrayList. Then send that new ArrayList to your BaseAdapter and set

```
notifyDataSetChanged().
```

Comment: can u give me some example of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned how you are inserting data to mysql database, whether it is from within your app or from the web (if you have made a site to insert products in your database with a form).

If data are inserted from web and not your android application, you can use [Google Cloud Messaging Service (GCM)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) to notify  your app when new products are inserted to database db update without having to refresh from within the app. Convert the new product details to a json string and pass it through GCM. See [this article](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139) and [this one](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) to set up using GCM.

Alternatively, you can use pusher library to do the same.  See pusher quick start for android [here](https://pusher.com/docs/android_quick_start).

If you are able to receive the json string for the new product, parse it in required form (in your case `HashMap<String, String>`) and add it to existing dataset like:
  `productsList.add(/*new HashMap from the received product json*/)`

Then you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```