# Can't set the data that is coming out as the response from the server to the CustomListView Adapter

Tags: java, android, json, listview

This is the Java code where I am parsing the data-

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
//         Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...Please Wait...");
        pDialog.show();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://sikkimexpress.itstunner.com/api/homenewslist/topnews", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("HomeNews");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject homenews = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Movie movie = new Movie();
                        String newsId = homenews.getString("NewsId");
                        String dateTime = homenews.getString("DateTime");
                        String newsType = homenews.getString("NewsType");
                        String title = homenews.getString("Title");
                        String description = homenews.getString("Description");
                        String mainImageURL = homenews.getString("MainImageThumbnail");

                        movieList.add(movie);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        System.out.println("Result:- " + newsId + " " + dateTime + " " + newsType + " " + title + " " + description + " " + mainImageURL);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
//                pDialog.hide();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("VOLLEY", error.getMessage());
//                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

This is the Model Class:-

```
public class Movie {
    private String newsId;
    private String dateTime;
    private String newsType;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String thumbnailUrl;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(String news_id, String date_time, String news_type, String news_title, String news_description, String news_thumbnailUrl) {
        this.title = news_title;
        this.thumbnailUrl = news_thumbnailUrl;
        this.newsId = news_id;
        this.dateTime = date_time;
        this.newsType = news_type;
        this.description = news_description;
    }

    public String getNewsId() {
        return newsId;
    }

    public void setNewsId(String newsId) {
        this.newsId = newsId;
    }

    public String getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public String getNewsType() {
        return newsType;
    }

    public void setNewsType(String newsType) {
        this.newsType = newsType;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }
}
```

The CustomListView Adapter:-

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView desciption = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desciption);

        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        title.setText(m.getTitle());
        desciption.setText(m.getDescription());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

There is no error while Parsing the data from server. I am getting the actual result. But the Progress Dialog is running after getting the data from the server. The data are not getting set in the CustomListView Adapter. I have already attached the code. Please Help me. I got stuck in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not closing your `Dialog` when you have your data.

You should not load data on the "main thread" - use a `AsyncTask` or something similiar to load your data. There you can show a progress dialog, before you start downloading your data:

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
       int count = urls.length;
       long totalSize = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
           totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
           publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
           // Escape early if cancel() is called
           if (isCancelled()) break;
       }
       return totalSize;
   }

   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
       setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
       showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
   }
}

 //Once created, a task is executed very simply:

 new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Also, don't set the adapter multiple times to your `ListView` (unless you use a different adapter), and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` everytime your underlying data changes. r data, show progress and stop the dialog when you are finished.

Comment: I am using volley. What to do with this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> But the Progress Dialog is running after getting the data from the server.?

ans: you are not closing the dialog in onResponse method

For listview you are not setting adapter with updated data. Please create a new adapter or follow this [How to update listview when back pressed from another activity android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430885/how-to-update-listview-when-back-pressed-from-another-activity-android/35431272#35431272)

Comment: I am using volley. What to do with this? Please help.

Comment: there is prob in your code with binding data to listview

Answer (score 0):

You need to dismiss progressdialog in this two response method to hide.

@Override public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { pDialog.dismiss(); }

@Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { pDialog.dismiss(); }

In onResponse() method after parsing json you need to notify adapter to display data in list.